# Avoid automatic shutdown

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, shutdown

I have a MacBook Pro running Lion. Usually, I need to run tasks that takes hours... so I just leave the laptop working before going to bed.

When I wake up, I notice that it tried to shutdown the system. How do I notice this? Well... all apps are closed except for iTerm (which always stops shutdown process when there is more than one tab open).

I tried to search the energy saving settings but there is nothing related to this... I would like to see how to prevent this behavior.

Comment: Related newer [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/143591/how-do-i-prevent-my-macbook-from-sleeping-when-downloading-apps-from-the-app-sto/) that has more answers.

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure your power adapter is connected to the Mac while you are sleeping.
2. In the Power Adapter section in Energy Saver, make the "computer sleep" -> "never".
3. You don't want your screen is on when you are in bed right? So make "Display sleep" -> some minutes.
4. Uncheck "Put the hard disk(s) to sleep when possible" and "Restart automatically if the computer freezes".

That should work!

Comment: I still found my Mac terminating process in this settings. (Thankfully the `Terminal` cannot be automatically terminated without user confirmation.) The `caffeinated` method mentioned in another answer show work better!

Answer (score 1):

You can also temporarily disable sleep from the command line with "caffeinate" regardless of the sleep settings in system preferences.

[image: caffeinate]

The basic function of caffeinate when run without any arguments it to prevent active sleep while caffeinate is running:

```
caffeinate
```

It will prevent active sleep until you stop caffeinate with "Control + C" or kill all caffeinate processes. After termination the MacBook will resume its normal behaviour (perfect for a computational intensive task)

You can also run caffeinate for a specific pre-determined amount of time to prevent sleeping for that specific amount of time e.g. 4 hours (specify time in seconds) - The ampersand makes the terminal run the process in the background so you continue working.

```
caffeinate -t 144000 &
```

Caffeinate can also be attached to other commands to prevent the MacBook from sleeping while the given command is being executed:

```
caffeinate [command_to_run] -arguments
```

For a full list of options please refer to the [man-page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/caffeinate.8.html)