# Prevent MacBook Pro 2016 from sleeping (High Sierra)

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, high-sierra, energy

I need to prevent my 13" 2016 MacBook Pro from sleeping. I'm using the Sonnet Echo Express III-D and when the Mac sleeps, all cards in the devices are disconnected and won't come back until the Mac is restarted or Thunderbolt 3 cable is removed and reconnected. I have a case open with Sonnet, but until then, I don't want my Mac to sleep.

The Mac is running High Sierra and there appears to be no setting in Energy Saver that keeps the Mac from going to sleep while on the Power Adapter, other than this:

[image]

In earlier versions of macOS, there used to be a second slider that allowed you to set when the Mac sleeps, in addition to controlling the display.

Now, no matter what, my Mac will sleep whenever it wants, with no apparent way of controlling this.

I have tried Amphetamine but it appears the way this works is, when the computer tries to go to sleep, it interrupts it and keeps it awake. This won't work for me, since that's long enough for the cards in the Sonnet to all get disconnected.

How can I prevent my Mac from sleeping?

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/143591/how-do-i-prevent-my-macbook-from-sleeping-when-downloading-apps-from-the-app-sto

Answer (score 6):

Use this on the terminal :

```
caffeinate -u -t <time_awake_in_secs>
```

It will keep the screen awake, avoid any restart till the time specified.

Use only

> caffeinate

if you want to endlessly keep the system awake.

To end this mode press control c or kill the terminal

Comment: I didn't know that binary, dope 

Comment: Awesome so we can put something like 5 years? 157680000 :-D

Answer (score 1):

[Anti Sleep](https://itunes.apple.com/app/anti-sleep-prevent-sleeping/id946798523) is a free app available on the App Store. It prevents Mac from going into sleep mode.

Comment: +1 for Anti Sleep. Recently updated and good ratings on the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

[NoSleep](https://integralpro.github.io/nosleep/) is a MacOS X kernel extension, preventing sleep when you close the lid.

Answer (score 1):

[KeepingYouAwake](https://github.com/newmarcel/KeepingYouAwake) is a small menu bar utility for macOS (Version 10.10 and newer) that can prevent your Mac from entering sleep mode for a predefined duration or as long as it is activated.

It can be easily installed using Homebrew cask by running:

`brew cask install keepingyouawake`

It is an alternative to widely popular tool [Caffeine](http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/) from Lighthead Software. Caffeine hasn't been updated in a while. KeepingYouAwake's icons are Retina-compatible and do look nice in the dark themed menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the freeware app [Caffeine](http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/).

I use it to make sure presentations don't go poof in front of the suits who approve my budgets.

Comment: You can also use the built-in command [`caffeinate`](http://brettterpstra.com/2014/02/20/quick-tip-caffeinate-your-terminal/)